# How do I proper implement try-except into this program?

Tags: python, try-except

I am taking an introduction to Python course and I cannot figure out how to add some try-except code to catch exceptions like zerodivisionerror and keyboardinterrupt. Full code below:

```
def math():
    x = float(0)
    Flag = True
    while(Flag):

        low_rng = input("Select your Lower range :")
        hi_rng = input("Select your Higher range :")
        num_1 = input("Enter your first number :")
        num_2 = input("Enter your second number :")
        add = float(num_1) + float(num_2)
        sub = float(num_1) - float(num_2)
        mult = float(num_1) * float(num_2)
        div = float(num_1) / float(num_2)



        def IsInRange():

            if float(num_1) < float(low_rng) or float(num_2) > float(hi_rng):
                print("The input values are out side the input ranges.") 
                print("Please check the numbers and try again.")
                print("Thanks for using our calculator.")
                IsInRange = False

            else:
                try:
                    print("The result of " + num_1 + " + "  + num_2 + " is " + str(add))
                    print("The result of " + num_1 + " - "  + num_2 + " is " + str(sub))
                    print("The result of " + num_1 + " * "  + num_2 + " is " + str(mult))
                    print("The result of " + num_1 + " / "  + num_2 + " is " + str(div))
                    IsInRange = True
                except ZeroDivisionError:
                    print("You can not divide by zero!")
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    print("User Interruption!")


        IsInRange()
        cont = input('Continue Looping y/n ')
        if(cont=="n"):
            print ("Ending loop")
            print("Done")
            Flag = False
        continue
math()
```

Comment: Hope it's not a college course. Posting your code here will probably flag up on submission if they have a system which checks for plagiarism. Read the docs man.

Comment: it is. crap I didn't even think about that. I desperately needed help. Oh well. Too late now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the print statements are not the place where exceptions happen.
ZeroDivisionError happens in

```
div = float(num_1) / float(num_2)
```

KeyboardInterrupt can happen any time after app started.

so try-except KeyboardInterrupt for the whole while block.

```
try 
    while(Flag):
        ....
except KeyboardInterrupt
    ...
```

and try-except ZeroDivisionError for the division statement.

```
try 
    div = float(num_1) / float(num_2)
except ZeroDivisionError 
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you. This took a little extra to make work but you definitely put me on the right track. My thought process was just a little off , but like I said. You helped me figure out how to make it work. Thank you